# How to delete focused row in tkinter python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I like to make a button deleting a speficied row using tkinter.

I have been trying this problem for a day.

How can I pick the one that has to be deleted? Thank you so much.

I would provide you with my code and the featured image made so far.

```
class Elements_Structure():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.tempList = [["Al", "Al", "Al.dat", "100", "nm"]]
        self.num_row = len(self.tempList)
        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NW, padx=20)

        label0 = Label(frame)
        label_elem = Label(label0, text="Elements Structure", font=("Arial", 13))

        self.label1 = Label(frame)
        label_measure = Label(self.label1, text="Number of Layers:")
        spin = Spinbox(self.label1, to=11, width=5)

        self.listbox = Label(frame)
        self.tempList.sort(key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)

        cols = ('L#', 'Layer Name', 'Material', 'Refractive Index', 'Thickness', 'Unit')
        self.add_button = Button(self.label1, text="Add", command=self.add_row)
        self.del_button = Button(self.label1, text="Delete", command=self.delete_row)
        self.listBox = Treeview(self.listbox, col=cols, show="headings")
        for col in cols:
            self.listBox.column(col, width=85)
            self.listBox.heading(col, text=col)

        self.final = Label(self.listbox)

        label0.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NW)
        label_elem.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NE)
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NE)
        label_measure.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NE)
        spin.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=NE)
        self.listbox.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=7, sticky=NW, pady=5)
        self.listBox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.add_button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=NE)
        self.del_button.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=NE)

    def add_row(self):
        self.num_row += 1
        for i, (layer_name, material, refractive_index, thickness, unit) in enumerate(self.tempList, start=1):
            self.listBox.insert("", "end", values=(i, layer_name, material,
                                                   refractive_index, thickness, unit))

    def delete_row(self):
        self.num_row -= 1
        l = list(self.listBox.grid_slaves(row=int(self.num_row)))
        for w in l:
            w.grid_forget()
```

and

```
from tkinter import *

class Main():
    self.root = Tk()
    Elements_Structure(Frame(self.root)).__init__(self.root)

Main().root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.listBox.curselection()` to get a tuple of the line(s) selected and use `self.listBox.delete(tuple)` to delete these/(those) lines.

Just assert that it's going to delete only one line otherwise change the `self.num_row -= 1`